# Leaflet Foreach point in GeoJSON check Distanceto

Tags: leaflet, javascript, php

So I was wondering how I can get the points from the
[GeoJSON located here](https://laerkeholt.dk/admin/get-features).

and then for each of them separately check if the distance of Markers is within 5 meters range of these. I have tried but not being able to call points from the GeoJSON and I'm wondering how I would get it to be specific for each of the Markers. So that the if statement return if any of the Markers from the GeoJSON is within 5 Meters of the "Hydrat" Markers below.

```
 var hydrat1 = [56.41083875205333, 8.864636421203615];
 var hydrat2 = [56.41069629842804, 8.868584632873537];
 var hydrat3 = [56.40941419180167, 8.866181373596193];
```

Here is the complete code I'm trying to use

```
function requestGeoJson(){
    fetch('https://laerkeholt.dk/admin/get-features')
      .then(function(response){ return response.json() })
      .then(function(json){
         geoJsonLayer.clearLayers().addData(json);
        // var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // var url = "https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/vandingsmaskine/with/key/";
          //http.open("POST", url, true);
          //http.send(JSON.stringify({"value1": "ID 1"}));
          var hydrat1 = [56.41083875205333, 8.864636421203615];
          var hydrat2 = [56.41069629842804, 8.868584632873537];
          var hydrat3 = [56.40941419180167, 8.866181373596193];


         setTimeout(requestGeoJson, 5000);
      });
};
requestGeoJson();
```

Comment: You can use turf.js

Comment: what? @neogeomat

Comment: don't know how to use that?. how am i going to do it using turf

Comment: @neogeomat How would I use that for my use case don't really know

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this a will help a little. I have an example where you click on a map and it gets the points within 150 miles of your click.  I also used a URL with JQuery's getJSON function.

If your data is on another site you usually get a CORS error, but if it doesn't change(static), go to the data site copy/paste into notepad and save it as a json file, than place it in the same folder as your HTML file and you will avoid the error.

http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Select/SelectPoints3.html or this one has a write up and working link. http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Select/SelectPoints4Explained.html

I didn't need turf for these. My examples used miles but radius is really meters. If you don't want to start off a mouse click, you have the coordinates of the three markers, just pass them one at a time in a loop.

Comment: Can't really figure out how to use that for my specific use case since I'm getting the GeoJSON from a URL @Bill Chappell

Comment: $.getJSON  can get the data from the url, or a file unless your getting a CORS error. If the data is on someone else's server, you're are probably going to get a CORS error. Hit F12 and check the console for the error message.

Comment: Checked the URL you are using and the coordinates are a string not number. ex ["8.91894","56.4098"]  Use  http://geojsonlint.com/ to see if the data you are looking at is good.

Comment: I'm not so intelligent so want to know how I can do what I described in the original post

Comment: what would i have todo?